# Что быстрее, чем Cupy в Python

Tags: python, numpy

Для перемножения (сложения) двух одномерных матриц размером 10е7 существует ли Numpy-подобный модуль быстрее, чем Cupy?

Comment: одномерная матрица - это вектор? или что?

Comment: можно попробовать сравнить `cupy` с [Numba on the GPU](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gpu-speedups/01_CuPy_and_Numba_on_the_GPU/index.html)